# How to extract data from json and inject it into chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chartist.js

I am making a bar chart component which I import in my `app.js`. My JSON data contains cricket match information i.e `season` and `runs` (i.e runs scored in that season). On Y-axis the height of bar will be sum of all the runs in particular season and on X-axis the labels would be the season.

For below JSON example:

```
season 2008 -> runs = 100+200=300
season 2009 -> runs = 300
season 2010 -> runs = 1100
season 2011 -> runs = 100
```

JSON data:

```
[
    { 
      "season":2008,
      "runs":100
    },
    { 
      "season":2008,
      "runs":200
    },
    { 
      "season":2009,
      "runs":300
    },
    { 
      "season":2010,
      "runs":600
    },
    { 
      "season":2010,
      "runs":500
    },
    { 
      "season":2011,
      "runs":100
    }   
]
```

Chart component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChartistGraph from 'react-chartist';

const ChartData = {

  //labels are the season

  labels: [ ],

  series: [
    // runs will be injected here
  ],
   distributeSeries: true
}

const options = {
    width: 720,
    height: 400
}

class Chart extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
         <ChartistGraph data={ChartData} type={'Bar'} options={options}/>
      </div>
    )}

}

export default Chart;
```

Instead of hardcoding the data from JSON data how can I inject `season` as `labels` and `runs` as `series`. I tried using for loop but I was not able to get sum of runs for a particular `season`. eg: for `season 2008` it should be 100+200=300 i.e label=2008 and series element corresponding to it will be `300`.

Note: For given JSON data series will be :

`series:[300, 300, 1100, 100]`

Comment: Have you tried anything *at all*?

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried looping but I want sum of runs for particular season as height of bars in bar chart and labels should be season but I am not able to figure out how to get sum of runs in corresponding season.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using array reduce to combine the seasons, and another reduce to create the two arrays

```js
var json = `[
    { 
      "season":2008,
      "runs":100
    },
    { 
      "season":2008,
      "runs":200
    },
    { 
      "season":2009,
      "runs":300
    },
    { 
      "season":2010,
      "runs":600
    },
    { 
      "season":2010,
      "runs":500
    },
    { 
      "season":2011,
      "runs":100
    }   
]`

var data = Object.entries(JSON.parse(json).reduce((acc, {season, runs}) => (acc[season] = (acc[season] || 0) + runs, acc), {}))
    .reduce((acc, [labels, series]) => (acc.labels.push(labels), acc.series.push(series), acc),{labels: [], series:[]}) 
    console.log(data)
```

Broken down in ES5, step by step

```js
var json = `[
    { 
      "season":2008,
      "runs":100
    },
    { 
      "season":2008,
      "runs":200
    },
    { 
      "season":2009,
      "runs":300
    },
    { 
      "season":2010,
      "runs":600
    },
    { 
      "season":2010,
      "runs":500
    },
    { 
      "season":2011,
      "runs":100
    }   
]`
var data = JSON.parse(json); // because JSON is a string representation of an javascript object
var data1 = data.reduce(function (acc, item) {
    var season = item.season,
        runs = item.runs;
    acc[season] = acc[season] || 0; // add a season as a key
    acc[season] += runs; // add runs
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(data1); 
var data2 = Object.entries(data1); // make an array of [[label, runs],[label, runs]...]
console.log(data2); 
var data3 = data2.reduce(function (acc, item) { // each item is an array of [year, total runs]
    var labels = item[0],
        series = item[1];

    acc.labels.push(labels);
    acc.series.push(series); 
    return acc;
}, { labels: [], series: [] }); // initialise the return object
console.log(data3);
```

Comment: Your code is hard to understand for a newbie like me but I will try to go through it.

Comment: well ... yes ... hang on

Comment: added an expanded ES5 version (well, almost ... still using template strings as a "dodge" for creating the JSON, but the JSON in the real code wont be hard coded anyway

Comment: As you have converted JSON into string what if new data is fetched ?

Comment: Json is a string! Just remove json.parse if you have actual array and not json as you said

Answer (score 1):

Create new array, loop through all elements of current array, parse them by their key and see if value is unique in our new array, if it's not add to that, if it is create new element.

```
function fillGraph(data){
var newArray = []; //creating new, empty array
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ //going through all elements of data array
        if(newArray.hasOwnProperty(data[i]["season"]){ //if it already has that season
            newArray["season"] += data[i]["runs"]; //add runs to the current season
        }else{
            newArray.push({data[i]["season"] : data[i]["runs"]}); //if not create new object with key name as a season name and assign runs
        }
    }
    for(var i in newArray) { //go through our new array
        chartData.labels.push(i); //push key name of current array element into graph labels property
        chartData.series.push(newArray[i]); //push value of current array element into graph series property
    });
}
```

Comment: `$.each` why have you introduce jquerey bloat when javascript can do that anyway!!!

Comment: @JaromandaX Oppsi, first thing that came to my mind. Naturally fastest way (I think?) :D I will edit. Btw, nice answer down there

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my take on the task

```
 <script>
            // in the url variable I use a link to my JSON, so might try you by 
            // firstly uploading your JSON at myjson.com
            let url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/8x9l7'; 

            fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then((out) => {
                // here you might try console.log(out); to check the correctness of 
                // displaying your JSON imported via URL
                convertJsonToData(out);
            }).catch(err => { throw err });

            let data = {
                    labels: [],
                    series: [[]]
                };

            function convertJsonToData(jsonData) { 
                for (let x in jsonData) {
                    data.labels.push(jsonData[x].transactTime); //transactTime and walletBalance are keys in my JSON, you will have yours
                    data.series[0].push(jsonData[x].walletBalance);
                };
                // here you might try console.log(data); to check the correctness of 
                // data display taken from JSON and modified to use in chart
                return data;
            };

             let options = {
                 showPoint: false,
                 lineSmooth: true,
                 fullWidth: true,
                 height: 700,
                 showArea:true,
            };

             new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);

          </script>
```